# xslt 1.0 to replace xpath references with the actual data in the same xml

Tags: xpath, reference, replace, xslt-1.0

i have some requirement, where i need to replace the references in the same xml file.
limitation is to use xslt 1.0 only.

below is my sample input xml.

```
    <org>
       <depts>
          <dept>
             <deptId>1009</deptId>
                <deptName>IT</deptName>
                <deptAccessCode>IT-1009</deptAccessCode>
          </dept>
          <dept>
             <deptId>2344</deptId>
             <deptName>BPO</deptName>
             <deptAccessCode>BP-2344</deptAccessCode>
          </dept>
          </depts>
          <employees>
             <employee>
             <name>abc</name>
             <dept>
              <REFERENCE>
                 <LocationXPath>/org/depts/dept[2]</LocationXPath>
              </REFERENCE>
          </dept>
          <employee>
       </employees>
</org>
```

now i want to replace the node REFERENCE with actual data at the XPath /org/depts/dept[2].
so the output xml should be like below.

```
    <org>
       <depts>
          <dept>
             <deptId>1009</deptId>
                <deptName>IT</deptName>
                <deptAccessCode>IT-1009</deptAccessCode>
          </dept>
          <dept>
             <deptId>2344</deptId>
             <deptName>BPO</deptName>
             <deptAccessCode>BP-2344</deptAccessCode>
          </dept>
          </depts>
          <employees>
             <employee>
             <name>abc</name>
             <dept>
             <deptId>2344</deptId>
             <deptName>BPO</deptName>
             <deptAccessCode>BP-2344</deptAccessCode>
          </dept>
          <employee>
       </employees>
    </org>
```

i have several REFERENCE nodes in different elements referencing to different xpaths across the xml tree, which i need to replace them with actual data.

```
<someWhereInTheXmlTree>
<sometag>
   <REFERENCE>
      <LocationXPath>some/reference[1]/to/a/node[3]/in/the[4]/same/xml</LocationXPath>
   </REFERENCE>
</sometag>
<someWhereInTheXmlTree>
...
<ffff>
<bbbb>
   <REFERENCE>
      <LocationXPath>abc/xyz[1]/node[4]/element</LocationXPath>
   </REFERENCE>
</bbbb>
<ffff>
```

please help me on this.
Thanks in advance for the help.

So far i have implemented one XSLT to replace the references but now i am facing unwanted empty name spaces.

Here is my XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:tib="http://www.tibco.com/bw/xslt/custom-functions"
xmlns="http://www.realestate.org/residential/2010/schemas" >

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" method = "xml" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:param name="myxml"  />
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:param name="isNodeToReplace"><xsl:call-template name="ReferenceCheck" /></xsl:param>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$isNodeToReplace='true'">
            <xsl:call-template name="replaceWithData">
                <xsl:with-param name="ref"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="ReferenceCheck">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="name(child::*[1])='REFERENCE' and name(child::*[1]//child::*[1])='LocationXPath'">true</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>false</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="replaceWithData">
    <xsl:param name="ref" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="tib:evaluate($myxml,$ref)" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

in the above XSLT i am passing the entire xml (same xml, which is being processed) as a parameter **$myxml**

Below is my sample input XML --this is just a snippet of xml,The actual xml file which i am dealing with is too large and contains so complex tree structure.How ever this sample xml is suffice enough to produce my problem.

Input file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<org xmlns="http://www.realestate.org/residential/2010/schemas">
    <depts>
        <dept>
            <deptId>1</deptId>
            <deptName>health</deptName>
            <deptAccessCode>HL007845</deptAccessCode>
        </dept>
    </depts>
    <employees>
        <employee>
            <name>TOM</name>
            <dept>
                <REFERENCE>
                    <LocationXPath>/org/depts/dept[1]</LocationXPath>
                </REFERENCE>
            </dept>
        </employee>
    </employees>
</org>
```

my output file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<org xmlns="http://www.realestate.org/residential/2010/schemas">
    <depts>
        <dept>
            <deptId>1</deptId>
            <deptName>health</deptName>
            <deptAccessCode>HL007845</deptAccessCode>
        </dept>
    </depts>
    <employees>
        <employee>
            <name>TOM</name>
            <dept xmlns="">
                <deptId>1</deptId>
                <deptName>health</deptName>
                <deptAccessCode>HL007845</deptAccessCode>
            </dept>
        </employee>
    </employees>
</org>
```

Where as Expected output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<org xmlns="http://www.realestate.org/residential/2010/schemas">
    <depts>
        <dept>
            <deptId>1</deptId>
            <deptName>health</deptName>
            <deptAccessCode>HL007845</deptAccessCode>
        </dept>
    </depts>
    <employees>
        <employee>
            <name>TOM</name>
            <dept>
                <deptId>1</deptId>
                <deptName>health</deptName>
                <deptAccessCode>HL007845</deptAccessCode>
            </dept>
        </employee>
    </employees>
</org>
```

so i am getting unwanted empty name space in << dept xmlns="">> in the replaced root element.
Hope this could clearly explain my problem
Thanks in Advance

ultimately i have found the solution at the link below to remove the unwanted empty name spaces.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/0de59291-ef3a-4a4c-9ca5-17923b16a504

Here is the new XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:tib="http://www.tibco.com/bw/xslt/custom-functions"
xmlns="http://www.realestate.org/residential/2010/schemas" >

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" method = "xml" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:param name="myxml"  />
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:param name="isNodeToReplace"><xsl:call-template name="ReferenceCheck" /></xsl:param>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$isNodeToReplace='true'">
            <xsl:call-template name="replaceWithData">
                <xsl:with-param name="ref"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="ReferenceCheck">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="name(child::*[1])='REFERENCE' and name(child::*[1]//child::*[1])='LocationXPath'">true</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>false</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="replaceWithData">
    <xsl:param name="ref" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="tib:evaluate($myxml,$ref)" mode="move-to-namespace">
        <xsl:with-param name="namespace" select="'http://www.realestate.org/residential/2010/schemas'" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*" mode="move-to-namespace">
    <xsl:param name="namespace" />
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{$namespace}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="move-to-namespace">
            <xsl:with-param name="namespace" select="$namespace"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text() | comment() | processing-instruction()" mode="move-to-namespace">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

if any xslt expert refines it further to avoid any unnecessary instruction with proper explanation its very glad.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi All,My XSLT processor supports the custom function tib:evaluate().Now i am able to replace the references with the actual data but i am getting unwanted empty name space in the replaced root element.

Comment: i am completely struck here.Experts please help me.

Comment: Sardar Ahamed, Glad you found the solution. There are several similar questions here at SO and I have answered some of them -- the basic principle when you want to get rid of some namespaces in the output is not to copy a node (or create it as a literal result element) but to re-create the node, using `xsl:element` (, or `xsl:attribute` for attributes). In the future, if you have a related question, ask this as a separate SO question -- otherwise your readers cannot see so well that you have updated the question and have additional questions. With a separate SO question you also earn more rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In general**:

- Not posiible in pure XSLT 1.0.
- Not possible in pure XSLT 2.0
- May be possible in pure XSLT 3.0 -- read about the
  **[`<xsl:evaluate>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-evaluate)** instruction.
- In XSLT 1.0 you may be lucky if your XSLT processor implements the    EXSLT **[`dyn:evaluate()`](http://www.exslt.org/dyn/functions/evaluate/index.html)** extension function (a few do).
  Otherwize, you will have to write an extension function to select the
  nodes and return them back.

If there are restrictions on the syntax of the XPath expressions,    then it may be possible to implement a pure XSLT 1.0 solution.

Comment: Hi dimitre, thanks for the quick response. I will check my xslt processor support for evaluate() function.mean while can you please explain the last part in your answer for the restrictions on the syntax of xpath expressipns then it is possible?

Comment: Hi Dimitre, i have updated the progress.My xslt processor supports tib:evaluate() custom funtion.now i am facing empty name spaces in the replaced elements.Please suggest how to remove the unwanted name spaces.

Comment: I have seen few other posts regarding the empty name space removal.but in my case, i need to use the copy-of instruction as i am generating the node dynamically ( <xsl:copy-of select="tib:evaluate($myxml,$ref)" /> )

Comment: @SardarAhamed: I think this is the subject of a new question. In the meantime you can decide to *accept* the best answer to your current question (by clicking the check-mark next to the answer).

Comment: Yes ,I have chosen best answer

Comment: @SardarAhamed, You are welcome. Please, think well and ask the additional question giving a good example (XML document, exact wanted result, rules that the transformation must implement), so that it will be easy to understand to the majority of readers -- this is how you can get good answers.

Comment: ,I have added more details of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in pure XSLT 1.0. You have to use extension function, e.g.  [Xalan evaluate expression](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensionslib.html#evaluate)